Euler-Lagrange equations for double integral, with single function of one variable
In Wikipedia's Euler-Lagrange (EL) page, there are many situations that are considered: functions of many variables, many derivatives, etc. My problem, though is not considered there, and I failed to derive the EL equations.
The integral I'm looking to minimize is of the form
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds L(f, f', t,s)
$$
where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and $f'$ is the derivative of $f$.
Therefore we have a double integral, but there is only one function, and it has only one variable... When I naively try the multi-variable case from Wikipedia, I'd get nonsensical equations, which would imply that $f(t)$ would depend on s...
As an arbitrary example to illustrate what I mean, consider equations (64)-(67) in this reference $$L = -\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{e^{i\phi(t)} - e^{i\phi(s)}}{(t-s)^2}$$
How do I derive the EL equation for this type of problem?

Is this integral from a reference? Which page?

A reference that does this type of calculation is for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9607137 on equation 64-67. The example I gave is too arbitrary, so I'll include the one from this reference in my question.

just an additional comment, the integral I want to minimize is not exactly this one, it's from a research problem. That being said, my problem is very fundamental, so understanding how this one was derived is likely good enough for me to!

Assuming that functional $ L(f,f^{\prime},s,t)$ is "regular enough", one can interchange the order of integration and the integral in $t$ becomes "part" of  a new functional that admits the one-dimensional case you are familiar with. You see the new functional $L_1$, would be given by $L_1(f,f^{\prime},s):=\int L(f,f^{\prime},s,t) dt$.

When you need to deal with a somewhat unusual functional, it is often safer to rederive the Euler-Lagrange equation from its differential instead of trying to apply a "ready-to-serve" recipe. In the present case, we want to study the functional $S[\phi] = \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}s \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}t \; L[\phi]$, with the following Lagrangian $-$ note that you miscopied the Eq. $(64)$ of the reference you linked $-$ :
$$
L[\phi] = \frac{e^{i\phi(t)-i\phi(s)}}{(t-s)^2}
$$
I omitted the normalization constant intentionally, because it doesn't play any significant role. As a first remark, it is to be noted that, since $S$ depends on one dependent variable only, namely $\phi$, then there will be a single Euler-Lagrange equation.
As said above, we can start from the functional differential of $S$ is given by $\delta S[\phi] = \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}s \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}t \; \delta L[\phi]$, with
$$
\delta L[\phi] = i\frac{e^{i\phi(t)-i\phi(s)}}{(t-s)^2}(\delta\phi(t)-\delta\phi(s)).
$$
Now, dividing by the quantity $\delta\phi(z)$, together with the "rule" $\frac{\delta\phi(x)}{\delta\phi(y)} = \delta(x-y)$, where the last $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta function, one gets
$$
\frac{\delta L[\phi]}{\delta\phi(z)} = i\frac{e^{i\phi(t)-i\phi(s)}}{(t-s)^2}(\delta(t-z)-\delta(s-z)),
$$
hence finally
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta\phi(z)} 
   &= i\int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}s \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}t \; \frac{e^{i\phi(t)-i\phi(s)}}{(t-s)^2}(\delta(t-z)-\delta(s-z)) \\
   &= ie^{i\phi(z)}\int_\Bbb{R}\frac{e^{-i\phi(s)}}{(s-z)^2}\mathrm{d}s - ie^{-i\phi(z)}\int_\Bbb{R}\frac{e^{i\phi(t)}}{(t-z)^2}\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= 2\operatorname{Im}\left(e^{i\phi(z)}\int_\Bbb{R}\frac{e^{-i\phi(\tau)}}{(\tau-z)^2}\mathrm{d}\tau\right)
\end{align}
$$
which corresponds to Eq. $(66)$ of the same reference.

Addendum : another example with $\phi'$.
Consider a Lagrangian involving a derivative and two times, such as $L[\phi] = \frac{1}{2}\phi(s)\phi'(t)^2$ for instance, whose functional differential is given by
$$
\delta L[\phi] = \frac{1}{2}\phi'(t)^2\delta\phi(s) + \phi(s)\phi'(t)\delta\phi'(t).
$$
As the functional derivative of $\phi'$ is $\frac{\delta\phi'(x)}{\delta\phi(y)} = \delta'(x-y)$, one has consequently
$$
\frac{\delta L[\phi]}{\delta\phi(z)} = \frac{1}{2}\phi'(t)^2\delta(s-z) + \phi(s)\phi'(t)\delta'(t-z),
$$
where $\delta'(t-z) \equiv -\delta(t-z)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ by an implicit integration by parts, hence finally
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta\phi(z)} 
   &= \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}s \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}t \; \frac{\delta L[\phi]}{\delta\phi(z)} \\
   &= \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}s \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}t \; \left(\frac{1}{2}\phi'(t)^2\delta(s-z) + \phi(s)\phi'(t)\delta'(t-z)\right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}\int_\Bbb{R}\phi'(t)^2\mathrm{d}t - \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=z}  \int_\Bbb{R}\phi(s)\phi'(t)\mathrm{d}s \\
   &= \int_\Bbb{R}\left(\frac{1}{2}\phi'(\tau)^2 - \phi(\tau)\phi''(z)\right)\mathrm{d}\tau
\end{align}
$$

Thanks a lot for the answer... If possible, could you clarify two additional points? How do I deal with derivatives in the functional (in my case the functional has the $f'$ terms)? And why do we have the final expression equals zero in equation 66, instead of the functional derivative of L equals zero?

@peep   1° I've added an example involving a derivative; take a look at it. 2° Regarding your second question (about Eq. (66) set to 0), it has to be recalled that the initial problem aims to determine the stationary points of the functional $S$, which is not equivalent to its Lagrangian due to integration.
